# NSString stringWithFormat "%" "d" 4 instead of "%d" 4?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to do the following where "%d",9 is done joining "%","d" <--- there is a reason to break up, to loop, ie:  %x %d %g %f where I loop just "x d g f"

```
lbl.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"%", @"d", 9]; <<--errors
```

- the desired output is "9" <-----

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first argument is the format, so you need another `stringWithFormat:` to take the generated format string. So something like:

```
bl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"%", @"d"], 9];
                                                               // ^ OR @"%%%@", @"%d" if only the 'd' is variable
```

Although it seems like an NSScanner or `-[NSNumber stringValue]` or something would be better suited to this kind of task.